# Table with twitter bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this js part of script:

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
     $("table_div").append("<td>" + value + "</td>");
 });
```

I want use this for create a table with twitter bootstrap. In the html page there is this table element:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table_div">
</table>
```

But this solution doesn't works. How I have to do? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have a table of the style of twitter bootstrap

Comment: What's the structure of `data`? Is it a simple array or a json object?

Comment: Is a json object. I have a matrix of couple timestamp:value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you're not appending any `<tr>` elements which are needed in a table, and secondly you're referring to `$("table_div")` instead of `$("#table_div")` (the hashtag `#` means that you're referring to an ID, just like in CSS).

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
     $("#table_div").append("<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I want a <table class="table"></table> element with rows and columns with data values.

Comment: @sharkbait What does your data look like?

Answer (score 5):

Besides referring to the node `<table_div>` instead of the id `#table_div` you don't want to append anything to the table node.

You should take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) as well as [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

You should use `tbody` when using **Twitters Bootstrap** anyways for example, like so:

```
<table id="table_div" class="table table-striped">
  <tbody></tbody>
<table>
```

here the right js

```
for (i in data) {
  $('#table_div > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>'+data[i]+'</td></tr>');
}
```

For more research look here [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

**Edit:**

Ok i wrote you an entire example using twitters bootstrap and jQuery.
This works, if it doesn't for your data array, something is wrong with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-striped" id="my-table">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = ["foo","bar"];
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
                $('#my-table > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>'+item+'</td></tr>');
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ha, true, it can't. `$.each(callback)`. There is no two option each.
You need to use regular foreach in javascript not $.each() from jQuery. It's for iterating all child nodes.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please provide more detail about `data`. Should if work, pleas don't forget to mark this as an answer, took me a while ;)

Comment: Um, *$.each(dataset,handler)* works just fine. It's *$('.el').each(handler)* that just accepts one argument.

Comment: Oh, right [this each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). This question is driving me insane.
@sharkbait could you pleas post a dump of data?

Comment: I John thank you for your help. I don't have a dump of data, but is a json data, formed by couples of "timestamp:value". I would create a table with this two column...

Comment: @sharkbait I added an entire demo. Pleas don't forget to give me some thumbs up ;) It it doesn't work with you data array, something must be wrong with it.